# What is the correct way to pass optional values to child widgets in Flutter

Tags: flutter

Maybe I am going about this the wrong way due to my experience with React. I am attempting to break down reusable code into smaller widgets in hopes of cleaning up the files since my only dislike with flutter so far is how unwieldy the widget tree becomes. Hopefully I can learn from this post. Below I have a form widget and I have tried to wrap the TextFormField widget with my own class `TextInputField`  to abstract away stuff like style widgets and other repeated code.

For the most part I have had little issues with making this work with one exception. When I want to make a passed in parameter optional I am having problems figuring out how to do that with some widgets. For example it is easy to make borderColor optional since I am setting a default value in the constructor, but I have not been able to figure out how to do this with the `controller`. I want the option to pass it in or not similar to how I would do that in React. However I cannot set the default value to `null`, therefore I have no choice and must pass the controller into the widget. This would be a common pattern for me and I am wondering if I am just doing this the wrong way of if my lack of experience with Flutter is the issue.

***What I have tried:***

1. Lot of searching.
2. Tried to use positioned instead of named parameters
3. And lots of blind attempts to manipulate code

How can I achieve this pattern?
Thanks.

***Parent Widget:***

```
Form(
  key: _formKey,
  autovalidateMode: _validate,
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      const TextInputField(
        onValidate: validateEmail,
        label: 'Email',
        labelColor: colorInputLabel,
        radius: 40,
        inputAction: TextInputAction.next,
      ),
      const SizedBox(height: inputFieldSpace),
      const TextInputField(
        onValidate: validatePassword,
        label: 'Password',
        labelColor: colorInputLabel,
        obscured: true,
        radius: 40,
        inputAction: TextInputAction.done,
      ),
      const SizedBox(height: 40),
      OnboardingButton(
        text: 'Register',
        onTap: () {
          context.read<SigninBloc>().add(ValidateSigninEvent(_formKey));
        },
      )
    ],
  ),
);
```

***Child Widget:***

```
class TextInputField extends StatelessWidget {
  final String label;
  final Function(String? value) onValidate;
  final Color borderColor;
  final Color labelColor;
  final TextInputControl controller;

  const TextInputField(
      {Key? key,
      required this.label,
      required this.onValidate,
      this.borderColor = const Color.fromRGBO(223, 222, 227, 1),
      this.labelColor = const Color.fromARGB(255, 183, 182, 187),
      this.controller = null,
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(

      *** Would like this to be optional like react ***
      controller: controller || null,
      *************************************************

      textInputAction: inputAction,
      obscureText: obscured,
      validator: (value) => onValidate(value),
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: label,
        labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: fontSize, color: labelColor),
        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: 20,
        ),
        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(radius),
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: borderColor),
        ),
        focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(radius),
          borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Just make it nullable?

Comment: Should it be `TextEditingController?`   instead of `TextInputControl`

Comment: lol that's cool. I really appreciate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you just want to change

```
final TextInputControl controller;
```

to

```
final TextInputControl? controller;
```

to make it nullable. Though your `TextInputField` class seems to be full of errors. Like the constructor is missing a `)`, `TextFormField` doesn't accept `TextInputControl` but `TextEditingController`. You haven't even defined `obscured`, `inputAction`, `fontSize` and `radius`

Comment: Yes, I pulled a bunch of code out just to shorten the example. Thank you.